# Is it possible to modify the "function call" at the preprocessing time or the compile time

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, macros, preprocessor-directive

**1st problem:** Is it possible to call a function with some parameters and it gets modify to something else after compilation either at preprocessing time or at compilation time into something like

```
#define func(a,b) func(a,sizeof(a),b)
```

Some may think why such a need arose.

Actually I am porting code in windows using visual studio 2010 and there is some functions which are deprecated like strcpy(), strcat(), etc. It says to use strcpy_s() instead.

I know I could have suppressed it using `#pragma disable(warning: )` or by providing flags like:

```
_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRRECATE
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

But I don't wan't to ignore or suppress them.

I tried to just simply replace the string instead of ignoring by using:

```
#define strcpy strcpy_s
```

as in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx I read there would be no mismatch of arguments if I don't provide the second arg.

I mean it should be ok if I use like this:

```
#define strcpy strcpy_s
strcpy(dest,src);
```

But its not. It still produce warning.

**Definition of strcpy_s is:**

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

**2nd problem:** The first argument is a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory so how can I get the size of the memory pointed by this pointer. Though I read that it's not feasible but there has to be some way(hopefully).

By the way what is `_countof(var)`?

Comment: Please, please don't do this. Either use the other versions or turn off those warnings.

Comment: 1. That isn't the only definition of `strcpy_s`, as you conveniently left out [**the template versions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) that deduce size from fixed arrays. 2. There is no *portable* way to acquire the size of a dynamic allocation given only its pointer to raw memory. I concur with the dr. Don't do this. If you want to use the safety versions of the runtime library, then *use them*. 3. `_countof` is [**documented here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx)

Comment: +1 Just because the possible solutions in the question are terrible doesn't mean this question is at all bad. As for an answer, avoid using non-standard functions if you need to build cross-platform. And don't fight the language too hard.

Comment: I suggest you to disregard the deprecation warnings. There is only one implementation of the C language (Microsoft) which claims that these functions are deprecated. Fact is, functions like `strcpy_s` do rarely provide extra security and are not available on most other platforms, greatly reducing the portability of your program.

Comment: 1.Sorry @WhozCraig my mistake I didn't thought function definition would change whether it's c or c++.
Actually I am working with C language specifically so the template version is out anyway.
2.You said **no portable way** so is there some other technique.

Answer (score 2):

These functions are **NOT** deprecated. Microsoft is trying to induce you to write Microsoft-specific code by falsely claiming they're deprecated even though the ISO WG14 committee (who's responsible for them) has made no such statement.

Defining the three `_CRT` macro's should be considered as the correct way to put the compiler into a "somewhat closer to the Standard" mode, just like `/Za`.

Answer (score 0):

As MSalters [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25890057/1741125), these functions aren’t deprecated, they’re part of standard C. They are safe if used properly and there’s nothing wrong with suppressing these warnings, especially, when writing portable code. (They (maybe only some of them, don’t know) are standardized in the Annex K of the C11 standard, which is not mandatory.)

> But I don’t want to ignore or suppress them.

Why? Not to suppress warnings isn’t a good thing in itself.

> I tried to just simply replace the string instead of ignoring by using:
>
> ```
> #define strcpy strcpy_s
> ```

That works for C++ only (and only for MS Windows, I don't know if C++ specifies something similar to C11’s Annex K) and even there, only for array arguments. In C, you can get a similar behaviour:

```
#define IS_ARRAY(arr) ((char *)(arr) == (char *)&(arr))
#define my_strcpy(a, b) ( assert(IS_ARRAY(a)) ,
                          strcpy_s((a), sizeof(a), (b)) )
```

or even a static assertion — e.g. Gcc allows this as a constant expression; the standard allows, but doesn’t require it — this would allow you to find all occurences of pointer arguments at compile time and “fix” them manually. (Again, this isn’t a fix, either the code is already safe with `strcpy` or it still isn’t, it’s just more likely to crash.)

As a note, the behaviour is undefined, if a macro with the name of a standard library function is defined (if the associated header is included). Thus, I assumed the `strcpy` calls are already replaced by `my_strcpy`.

(As another note, always parenthesize your macro arguments, as shown above.)